# Elements going beneath div for position = fixed

Tags: css

When I give position = fixed, elements on the right side is going beneath the black menu bar shown on the left side.

What is the way to make sure the yellow container starts only from the point the black container ends?

```css
.menubar {

  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: none;
   position: fixed;

}

   .grid--1x2{
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

.grid {
    display: grid;
  }
  
.overflow {
overflow:auto;

}  

.rightside
{
background:yellow;
margin-bottom:"100px"
}
```

```html
            <div className='grid grid--1x2 grid--3070'>
  <div class="menubar">This is left side menu bar</div>
      <div >
          <div class='overflow'>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` on your menu bar will remove it from the document flow. This means that your `fixed` elements will float on top of everything else.

One way to solve the issue would be to give your `overflow` class a `margin-left` that is the same width as your menubar.

```css
.menubar {

  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: none;
   position: fixed;

}

   .grid--1x2{
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

.grid {
    display: grid;
  }
  
.overflow {
overflow:auto;
margin-left: 170px;
}  

.rightside
{
background:yellow;
margin-bottom:"100px"
}
```

```html
            <div className='grid grid--1x2 grid--3070'>
  <div class="menubar">This is left side menu bar</div>
      <div >
          <div class='overflow'>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              <h1 class="rightside" >hello world</h1>
              
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```